# How can I visualize and calculate the volume of this $3$-dimensional object?

Tags: plotting, visualization

I have the following $3$-dimensional object defined by the inequalities:

$$
u ≥ 0, v ≥ 0, w ≥ 0, \sin u ≤ \cos v, \sin v ≤ \cos w, \sin w ≤ \cos u.
$$

How can I ''visualize'' this object in 3D using Mathematica? Furthermore, can I use Mathematica to automatically calculate its volume?

Comment: With kglr's solution: `ir = ImplicitRegion[Sin[u] <= Cos[v] && Sin[v] <= Cos[w] && Sin[w] <= Cos[u],{{u, 0, 4 Pi}, {v, 0, 4 Pi}, {w, 0, 4 Pi}}];` try `Volume@DiscretizeRegion@ir`

Comment: @rmw Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`RegionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html):

```
RegionPlot3D[Sin[u] <= Cos[v] && Sin[v] <= Cos[w] && Sin[w] <= Cos[u],
   {u, 0, 4 Pi}, {v, 0, 4 Pi}, {w, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 90]
```

[image]

Or use [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html):

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[Sin[u] <= Cos[v] && Sin[v] <= Cos[w] && Sin[w] <= Cos[u],
     {{u, 0, 4 Pi}, {v, 0, 4 Pi}, {w, 0, 4 Pi}}];

RegionPlot3D[ir, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to compute its volume numerically?

Comment: @Klangen, try  `RegionMeasure@ir` or `Volume@ir` .

Answer (score 3):

I question the accuracy of the volume calculated by DiscretizeRegion:  Just excise one out of the bunch to get the plot:
[image]

First compute the volume via DiscretizeRegion:

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[
  Sin[u] <= Cos[v] && Sin[v] <= Cos[w] && 
   Sin[w] <= Cos[u], {{u, Pi/2, 3 Pi}, {v, Pi/2, 3 Pi}, {w, Pi/2, 
    3 Pi}}]; Volume@DiscretizeRegion@ir
```

**Results:  32.54**

Now do a Monte-Carlo integration series from 5000 to 1000000 points:

```
myTable = Table[
   myPts = RandomReal[{Pi/2, 3 Pi}, {num, 3}];
   pts = Length@
     Select[myPts, (Sin[#[[1]]] <= Cos[#[[2]]] && 
         Sin[#[[2]]] <= Cos[#[[3]]] && Sin[#[[3]]] <= Cos[#[[1]]]) &];
   pts/num (5 Pi/2)^3 // N, {num, 5000, 1000000, 5000}];
```

and plot the results and do a Fit of the data:

[image]

Fit[myTable, {1, x}, x]

**34.9067 -0.000148992 x**

which appears to be settling on a value significantly higher than 32.5 computed by DiscretizeRegion.

Comment: It appears a smaller `MaxCellMeasure`, say `0.001`, is needed for `DiscretizeRegion` (or `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`) to get a accuracy result.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about MaxCellMeasure.  I got 34.86 with MaxCellMeasure->0.0001.